# how to put the data with combobox to another form?

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a payment system and what I really want to happen is that when I select the payment type(full or installment) the data that I inputted will show on another form.

For example, after I filled up my information and selected the payment method, and after I saved it, if my payment method is "full", the information will appear on the "full_pay" form or if I selected "installment_pay" the information will appear on the "installment" form.

```
if paytype.text="Full" Then
   'the info will go to the full_pay form
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write propertys in your new form and pass them from your old form

```
'Code on Main form to open form and Set parameters
 Dim frmFull_pay As New full_pay
 frmFull_pay.paytype = paytype.text
 frmFull_pay.show()

'Code on full_pay
    Private _paytype As String
    Public Property paytype As String
        Get
            Return _paytype 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _paytype = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Now you can access all the data you set on Porpertys

Comment: hi, i am sorry, i forgot to mention that i am using a listview to view the information of the student. and i use textbox to fill the information. i would like to show the information inputted in the textbox and sort the "full" and "installment" in different forms and view it on the listbox. hope you can help me